# In a module, using a defined resource works in puppet3, but fails in puppet5

Tags: puppet

All is in the *manifests* directory.

In manifest *execute.pp*, I have:

```
define execute (
   String $command         = "echo",
   String $workdirectory   = "/tmp",
   String $runas           = "www",
   Boolean $failonerror    = true  
) {
    # Resources
    require stdlib
    etc ...
```

The code which uses it :

```
 ....
 if defined(Execute["$titlePreviousExecRes"]) {
 ....
```

The error with puppet5 is

> Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Resource type not found: Execute at ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your defined type's manifest is physically located among those of a module (whose name you have not disclosed), but the type is not part of the module, in the sense that its name is not in the module's namespace.  As a result, Puppet's loader will not find it.  Your code was buggy for Puppet 3, too, but it seems to have benefited from a confluence a laxness features.

If your defined type is supposed to belong to a module named "mymodule", for example, then it should be explicitly declared in that namespace:

```
define mymodule::execute ( ...
```

and it should also be *referenced* via that namespace:

```
if defined(Mymodule::Execute["$titlePreviousExecRes"]) {
```

.  Fix your problem by placing your defined type in the correct namespace, and referring to it via its fully-qualified name.

---

As for why it seemed to work in Puppet 3, version 3 of the Puppet language supposed that references to classes and types that were not explicitly anchored to top scope (e.g. `::execute`) might be *relative* to the namespace of the class or type in which the reference appeared (or even to some others).  In your case, then, the autoloader would first guess that your reference to a type named `Execute` might be intended to refer to `::mymodule::execute`.  Seeing that a manifest `mymodule/manifests/execute.pp` exists, it would evaluate that file, and thereby obtain a definition of type `::execute` -- *not* the `::mymodule::execute` it was looking for.

Having not found the type it was looking for, the autoloader would then search in other namespaces, until ultimately trying top scope.  When it got there, however, it would find that it already had the top-scope definition it obtained from the manifest in the module, so the loader would succeed, providing that misplaced definition.  But that would only work for references from within the same module, and it presented a grave risk of collisions.

Puppet 5's autoloader still exhibits some fallback behavior for locating class and defined type definitions, but Puppet no longer recognizes relative class and defined type names.  Thus, when trying to resolve your reference to type `execute`, the autoloader never considers evaluating `mymodule/manifests/execute.pp`, because that's where it would expect to find `::mymodule::execute`, not the type it's looking for, `::execute`.

Thus, no, your definition is never located or loaded.  This is a feature, not a bug.